# Force https on Windows server

Tags: windows, http, https, server

I have a windows server online and some pages load in http I would like to force them to https how could I do that ?

I have no idea where to start

Comment: Do you have access to cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the code to the following in the `.htaccess` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

You can reffer the following blog for reference if this doesn't work.
https://www.catalyst2.com/knowledgebase/server-management/how-to-force-https-on-linux-and-windows-servers/